# Update a unix timestamp php (strtotime)

Tags: php, strtotime

I want to update a unix timestamp and add x months.

This is a timestamp that i use 1456256866

```
 strtotime("+1 month")
```

what i want to accieve is :

```
$time = '1456256866';
    //update $time with x months something like
$time("+5 month");
```

Can someone put me in the right direction?

Much Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such operations You should use `Datetime` class, especially `Add` method:

```
$date = new DateTime('@1456256866');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P5M'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
```

Check more here: http://php.net/manual/pl/datetime.add.php

Comment: Thanks,
This has solved my question.
I did not know of the Datetime class

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like below. the function `strtotime` takes a second argument.

```
$time = 1456256866;
$time = strtotime('+5 month', $time);
```